# Disable Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V Shortcuts in Pantheon Terminal for Juno

Tags: release-juno, pantheon-terminal

I use NeoVim and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> is a reserved key for multiline select. In the past, I was able to use `dconf` to disable these shortcuts.

Is there still a way to do this in Juno?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dconf-key is located under `/io/elementary/terminal/settings/natural-copy-paste`. If you change that value to false, `Ctrl+C` and `Ctrl+V` shouldn't be copying/pasting text anymore.

Comment: Choosing this as the answer since it was the first one posted.

Answer (score 2):

[image: i use dconf-editor]

you can use dconf-editor, and browse to `/io/elementary/terminal/settings/`